# .Cpanel.yml file Configuration for node app deployment

Tags: node.js, git

I'm having a little trouble deploying my app and am a little unsure if my .cpanel.yml file is configured correctly, as right now, when you go to the domain, you only see the index of/ and then the directory folder. Everything else seems to be find, no errors, repo and all deployed, npm/node registered and running.

My current config is this:

```
---
deployment:
 tasks:
 - export DEPLOYPATH=/home/deltade4/public_html
 - /bin/cp -R /home/deltade4/repositories/DeltaDesigns22 $DEPLOYPATH
 - /bin/cp node_modules $DEPLOYPATH
 - /bin/cp -R public $DEPLOYPATH
 - /bin/cp -R views $DEPLOYPATH
 - /bin/cp -R images $DEPLOYPATH
 - /bin/cp -R css $DEPLOYPATH
 - /bin/cp app.js $DEPLOYPATH
 - /bin/cp package.json $DEPLOYPATH
```

However, I came across this one on git which is an 'example node running on cpanel'.  I'm not sure if I should be added something along the lines of /bin/mkdir -- to also make a directory? It doesn't say to do so here : https://docs.cpanel.net/knowledge-base/web-services/guide-to-git-deployment/#deploy-an-entire-directory

Of which I've followed. Can't figure out what I'm missing!

Thanks

```
---
deployment:
  tasks:
    - export DEPLOYPATH=/home/$USER/nodejsapp
    - /bin/mkdir $DEPLOYPATH
    - /bin/cp app.js $DEPLOYPATH
    - /bin/cp package.json $DEPLOYPATH
    - /bin/cp script.sh $DEPLOYPATH
    - /bin/mkdir $DEPLOYPATH/tmp
    - /bin/touch $DEPLOYPATH/tmp/restart.txt
    - /bin/chmod +x $DEPLOYPATH/script.sh
    - cd $DEPLOYPATH
    - /bin/sh ./script.sh
```